# ¿Cómo sacar los registros con MySQL y/o codeigniter donde el usuario logueado no esté registrado?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, codeigniter

Tengo una tabla principal **comunidades_grupos** para crear comunidades. En una segunda tabla **comunidad_grupo_usuario** relaciono el **id** de **comunidades_grupos** y el **id_usuario** donde el mismo se ha ido uniendo. Deseo sugerirle al usuario los grupos dónde aún no pertenece pero la siguiente sentencia me sigue trayendo los grupos donde este ya es miembro y no quiero ese resultado:

```
    SELECT *
FROM (`comunidades_grupos` cg)
JOIN `comunidad_grupo_usuario` cgu ON `cg`.`id`=`cgu`.`id_grupo`
WHERE `cgu`.`id_usuario` != '1'
GROUP BY `cg`.`id`
ORDER BY `cg`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 6
```

de igual forma relaciono el query hecho en codeigniter:

```
 public function obtenerGruposSugeridos(
    $usuarioId
  ) {
    $this->db->select();    
    $this->db->from('comunidades_grupos cg');
    $this->db->join('comunidad_grupo_usuario cgu', 'cg.id=cgu.id_grupo');
    $this->db->where('cgu.id_usuario !=', $usuarioId);
    $this->db->group_by('cg.id');
    $this->db->order_by('cg.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit(6);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Opción 1:

- Crear una sub-consulta donde buscamos los grupos a lo que pertenece el usuario

  ```
   SELECT id_grupo 
   FROM comunidad_grupo_usuario
   WHERE id_usuario = [ID] # reemplazar por el id del usuario
  ```
- Movemos esa sub-consulta al `WHERE` e indicamos que el `cg.id` no este (`NOT IN`) en dichos registros

**Ejemplo:**

```
SELECT cg.*
FROM comunidades_grupos AS cg
WHERE cg.id NOT IN (SELECT id_grupo 
   FROM comunidad_grupo_usuario
   WHERE id_usuario = 1)
ORDER BY cg.id DESC
LIMIT 6
```

#### Opción 2:

Buscamos los `comunidades_grupos` y hacemos un `LEFT JOIN` de la tabla `comunidad_grupo_usuario` donde `cg.id = cgu.id_grupo` **y `cgu.id_usuario = [ID]`**.
De esta forma los registros de `comunidades_grupos` donde no este el usuario tendrán a si izquierda `NULL` registros de `comunidad_grupo_usuario`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
SELECT cg.*
FROM comunidades_grupos AS cg
   LEFT JOIN comunidad_grupo_usuario A cgu
       ON cgu.id_grupo = cg.id
       AND cgu.id_usuario = 1
WHERE cgu.id_grupo IS NULL
ORDER BY cg.id DESC
LIMIT 6
```

***Comentario:*** La velocidad de esta consulta dependerá de que tengas creado UN indice con AMBAS columnas (`id_grupo y id_usuario`) en la tabla `comunidad_grupo_usuario` para el `JOIN`